# comparison between two sequences for being the candidate for cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: (1,4) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function and let $\{a_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(1,2)$. Let $x_n=a_n^2f(a_n^2)$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{1+a_n^2}f(a_n^2)$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Which of the following statements is true?

(A) Both $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ must be Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$

(B) $\{x_n\}$ must be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ but $\{y_n\}$ need not be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$

(C) $\{y_n\}$ must be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ but $\{x_n\}$ need not be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$

(D) Neither $\{x_n\}$ nor $\{y_n\}$ needs to be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

how can I solve this problem. totally stuck on it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! It's usually best to type out your questions to ease searching. I'll edit it, but if you don't know LaTeX, you can find info in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

For example, is it true that for any $\,\epsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,N\in\Bbb N\,$ s.t.

$$n,m>N\Longrightarrow |x_n-x_m|=|a_n^2f(a_n^2)-a_m^2f(a_m^2)|<\epsilon\;?$$

You may want to try to write here

$$|a_n^2f(a_n^2)-a_m^2f(a_m^2)|=\left|a_n^2f(a_n^2)-a_m^2f(a_n^2)+a_m^2f(a_n^2)-a_m^2f(a_m^2)\right|\le$$

$$\le|a_n^2-a_m^2||f(a_n^2)|+|a_m^2||f(a_n^2)-f(a_m^2)|$$

It would also be helpful to remember that both a Cauchy  sequence and a (uniformly or not) continuous function on a closed finite interval are bounded...

(Question: where does the uniform continuity of $\,f\,$ play a role?)